# how to center a tweet?

Tags: html, css, tweets

Twitter provides the code to embed a tweet. For example I have:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>NoSQL space gradually becoming SlowSQL space.</p>&mdash; Big Data Borat (@BigDataBorat) <a href="https://twitter.com/BigDataBorat/statuses/349216251853287425">June 24, 2013</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I have tried to enclose the above code into a tag `<div style="margin:auto">...</div>` but the tweet appears yet aligned on the left. How to center it horizontally in a whatever page?

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same issue and the only solution worked for me was to change the class

**Before**

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
```

**After**

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet tw-align-center" data-lang="en">
```

Answer (score 2):

What really works if you are using the embed-code from Twitter is the addition of the class `tw-align-center` to the `blockquote` tag [as shown by Panayiotis Georgiou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41089962/1970617).

However, in my [Octopress](http://octopress.org)-based blog I use a [Jekyll-plugin](https://github.com/rob-murray/jekyll-twitter-plugin) and can't work directly with the HTML. Also, I don't want to fumble around with each and every embedded tweet separately.

Therefore I added the following to my CSS:

```
.twitter-tweet {
   margin: auto;
}
```

This works globally for the whole site with tweets added directly via the embed code and also for the tweets embedded by the plugin.

(via: [SpectrumZ](http://spectrumz.com/automtically-center-align-embedded-tweets/))

Answer (score 1):

Try `text-align:center;` on the `<p>`

**For Instance:**

```
<p style="text-align:center;">NoSQL space gradually becoming SlowSQL space.</p>
```

or if you want the whole block to be center, you can apply a `text-align:center;` to the `<blockquote>`

**For Instance:**

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" style="text-align:center;"><p>NoSQL space gradually becoming SlowSQL space.</p>&mdash; Big Data Borat (@BigDataBorat) <a href="https://twitter.com/BigDataBorat/statuses/349216251853287425">June 24, 2013</a></blockquote>
```

Here is the **[WORKING SOLUTION FOR BOTH](http://jsfiddle.net/gUBJv/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Give the class `e-entry-title` a `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style='width:100%'>
    <div style='width:50%;margin:0px auto'> 
        <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p>NoSQL space gradually becoming SlowSQL space.</p>&mdash; Big Data Borat (@BigDataBorat) <a href="https://twitter.com/BigDataBorat/statuses/349216251853287425">June 24, 2013</a></blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```