# Hugo Shortcode that uses JSON throws "bad character U+0022 error"

Tags: twitter, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I’m trying to make a shortcode with two parameters, a CSS class and a Tweet ID. My starting point is this example https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#tweet that shows how the default Hugo Twitter shortcode is used

`{{< tweet 877500564405444608 >}}`

But I want to use it like this in `post.md`:

`{{< tweet-single class="alignright" id="877500564405444608" >}}`

to produce the html:

```
<div class="tweet-in-post alignright">
<twitter-widget class=....
</div>
```

but using this in `tweet-single.html`

```
<!-- tweet-single -->

<div class="tweet-in-post {{ .Get "class" }}">

{{ (getJSON "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/oembed.json?dnt=1&hide_thread=1&id={{ .Get "id" }}") }}

</div>
```

gives me the error `bad character U+0022 ‘"’`.

These docs https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/#call-the-functions-with-a-url show how to call JSON function in Hugo, but I don't know how to use those examples to get my shortcode to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to customize a built-in shortcode is to start from its code.

The link you provide shows *how to use* the tweet shortcode, but it doesn't show what its code actually looks like. It takes some digging into the Hugo source code to actually find what the built-in shortcodes look like.

You can find them here: https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/tree/master/tpl/tplimpl/embedded/templates/shortcodes.

As of the current commit (`67f9204`), this is what the twitter shortcode looks like:

```html
{{- $pc := .Page.Site.Config.Privacy.Twitter -}}
{{- if not $pc.Disable -}}
{{- if $pc.Simple -}}
{{ template "_internal/shortcodes/twitter_simple.html" . }}
{{- else -}}
{{- $url := printf "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=%v&dnt=%t" (index .Params 0) $pc.EnableDNT -}}
{{- $json := getJSON $url -}}
{{ $json.html | safeHTML }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

So that is your starting point.

But this example is particularly tricky because this shortcode uses a style set up by the twitter api and it is particularly hard to fiddle with it.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17289753/9210961) can help you there.

Another difficulty here is that, if you look at the twitter shortcode, you can see that the tweet ID is not called by `{{ .Get "ID" }}` (a named params), but by `(index .Params 0)` (a positional params). And Hugo does not let you mix named and positional params.

So you cannot use something like `{{ .Get "class" }}` as you tried. Instead, you need to use a positional params such as `{{ .Get xx }}`, `xx` being the position of your params within the shortcode call.

**Here is a possible solution:**

```html
{{- $pc := .Page.Site.Config.Privacy.Twitter -}}
{{- if not $pc.Disable -}}
{{- if $pc.Simple -}}
{{ template "_internal/shortcodes/twitter_simple.html" . }}
{{- else -}}
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet tw-align-{{ .Get 0 }}" data-lang="en">
  {{- $url := printf "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=%v&dnt=%t" (index .Params 1) $pc.EnableDNT -}}
  {{- $json := getJSON $url -}}
  {{ $json.html | safeHTML }}
</blockquote>
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

As you can see, I added some `<blockquote>` customization, following the answer of the post I mentioned above and I am using `{{ .Get 0 }}` for the position. This means that I now have to adjust the params position for the tweet ID to `1`.

If you name this shortcode `tweet-single.html`, you can then call it with:

```html
{{< twitter-single right 877500564405444608>}}
```

to have the tweet to the right.

To have the tweet centered, it would be:

```html
{{< twitter-single center 877500564405444608>}}
```

Note that `right` or `center` do not take quotes since they are positional params.

---

**Alternative approach:**

If this approach does not work for you for some reason, a totally different approach would be to re-create the entire formatting of the tweet (without using what the twitter api does).

This is what Hugo does if you use `twitter_simple.html` instead of `twitter.html`.

If you look at `twitter_simple.html`, you can see that they are omitting the styling script and are instead recreating some simpler formatting for the `.twitter-tweet` class:

```html
{{- $pc := .Page.Site.Config.Privacy.Twitter -}}
{{- $sc := .Page.Site.Config.Services.Twitter -}}
{{- if not $pc.Disable -}}
{{- $id := .Get 0 -}}
{{- $json := getJSON "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?id=" $id "&omit_script=true" -}}
{{- if not $sc.DisableInlineCSS -}}
{{ template "__h_simple_twitter_css" $ }}
{{- end -}}
{{ $json.html | safeHTML }}
{{- end -}}

{{ define "__h_simple_twitter_css" }}
{{ if not (.Page.Scratch.Get "__h_simple_twitter_css") }}
{{/* Only include once */}}
{{  .Page.Scratch.Set "__h_simple_twitter_css" true }}
<style type="text/css">
  .twitter-tweet {
  font: 14px/1.45 -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen-Sans,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
  border-left: 4px solid #2b7bb9;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  color: #555;
}
  .twitter-tweet a {
  color: #2b7bb9;
  text-decoration: none;
}
  blockquote.twitter-tweet a:hover,
  blockquote.twitter-tweet a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

You can play with this code until you have a customization that suits you.

Comment: Thanks! Those work great. I went with my own CSS rather than the blockquote.

Comment: Glad I could help.